# How does this work? x<<=3 = -8 where (byte)x = 127?

Tags: java, c, logic, unsigned

**Why I am getting this output ?**

Byte x ;
x = 127;
x<<=3;//same as x = x <<3
println(x)

**output : -8**

When i note down it in paper and twiddled the bits I was getting - **11111000 and that is = 248**?

I suppose Byte occupies 1 byte (8 bits) .Dont know whether it is signed or unsigned?I assuem it to be signed?

**because the given below code in C gave me -8 as well:**

signed char x = 127;
x<<=3;
printf("the values of x = %d \n " , x);

Why -8??
rgd
softy

Comment: The C code is not well-defined - the shift produces the value 1016, and if that is outside the range of `signed char` then the result is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because `byte` is a signed data type which uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). And `248-256` is equal to `-8`.

Comment: +1 I would write `byte` rather than `Byte` and `(byte) 248` == `-8`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using signed char, which range is -128 to 127..
Most Significant Bit (MSB) for signed char is restricted to their signed..
0 for positve ,, 1 for negative.

If positive..
The value is counted normally.

But if negative..
The value is count [normal_value] - [max_value]
ex:

129 = 1000 0001 [bit]

so the vallue for signed = 129 - 256 = -127

CMIIW